# Motion Tracking vs Blob Tracking

Tags: opencv, motion-detection, emgucv

Hi all I have a simple question that I have been struggling with....what is the difference, if any, between motion component (blob?) tracking and blob tracking? As defined by OpenCV.

1. Does one cover the other? or are they entirely different things?
2. Can they be used in conjunction to improve tracking accuracy?
3. Is the former designed for motion while the latter for (relatively) static objects?

Thanks for helping out a newbie.

p.s. I am using Emgu (on .NET) and my terminology might reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blob tracking means detecting a blob over incoming frames. It will involve motion if the blob moves.

Motion tracking is quite general, and involves detecting motion over incoming frames. Motion tracking will involve blob tracking if you use a blob for detection, but there are other techniques like tracking like finding descriptors which don't involve blob.

Anyway I don't like the expression motion tracking, I prefer to say moving objects tracking.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_tracking) and [OpenCV page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/VideoSurveillance)? It seems both are almost same after reading that.

Blob is some part of image which has a different brightness or color from remaining part. So you need to identify blobs in each frame of the video.